# what does if(i-2) mean in C language?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

So,I understand everything in code except this `if` statement - `if(i-2)` :

```
for (i = -1, j = 0; i < 4; i++, j++)
    if (i - 2) 
       printf("%d\t", j * (i + 2));
```

Can anyone explain meaning of this `if` statement,does it have any influence on `printf` ? Thanks.

Comment: You can think of `if (expression)` as of `if (expression != 0)`.

Comment: `if (i - 2)` would be more sensibly written as `if (i != 2)`. The meaning is the same (apart from the possibility of the subtraction overflowing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement under an `if` is executed if the controlling expression is true.  In C, an expression that evaluates to 0 is considered false, while any other value is considered true.

So `if (i-2)` means the `printf` will get executed if `i-2` is non-zero, i.e. when `i` is not equal to 2.

Comment: It's the same as `if (i != 2)` .

Answer (score 1):

In C, an integer is treated like a boolean in an `if` statement:

- 0 is false
- not-zero is true

So `if (i-2)` is equivalent to `if (i != 2)`.

Comment: "an integer is treated like a boolean in an if statement:" - No! A boolean has exactly two values, `0` and `1`. It actually **is** an integer type. But here we have an `int`, which is different.

Comment: Maybe we're talking about different flavors of C. In my experience, a boolean [really is an integer](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdbool.h.html), Regardless, it is always treated like a boolean in an if statement.

Comment: There are no "different flavours" of C. It is a standardised language, not like C# or Java. Maybe you should read ISO9899:2011 (current version). Let apart `stdbool.h` is not necessary for this, as it just defines some macros. You seem to confuse _integer_ and `int`. (read my comment carefully again). And "**A boolean** is always treated like a boolean in an if statement" does not make sense. A boolean is always treated as a boolean - independent of the expression.

Comment: [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) is a flavor of C that introduced a boolean type.

Comment: C99 is the **previous** version of the C standard, not a "flavour". It has been canceled with the release of the third revision, i.e. ISO9899:2011. Please read the standard, including the foreword!

Answer (score 0):

In c any value can be used in an `if` statement not just boolean expressions. This devolves into expression != 0. Often this is against style guides as it can be confusing and error prone.

The two following are equivalent

```
if (val) ...
if (val != 0) ...
```

So in you're case

```
if (i - 2)
```

will be true for every value of `i` except `2` when `i-2` is `0`